# sql self join or other way to retrieve matching rows for specified columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, self-join

I want to retrieve data from table "Spots" where spot is in same hour for same StationCode, SalesHouse, ProgramName, Day, date and timeHour

E.g. I have data as below in table.

[image: Data in table Spot as below]

And I want a query which can retrieve data as below:

[image: output data]

Any code will be very helpful.

I try with self joins but not successful as of now.

Thank You.

Comment: Please post the code that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Spots s
INNER JOIN
(SELECT StationCode, SalesHouse, ProgramName, day, Date, TimeHour
FROM Spots
GROUP BY StationCode, SalesHouse, ProgramName, day, Date, TimeHour
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) j
ON s.StationCode = j.StationCode
AND s.SalesHouse = j.SalesHouse
AND s.ProgramName = j.ProgramName
AND s.day = j.day
AND s.Date = j.Date
AND s.TimeHour = j.TimeHour
```